# Chrome doesn't support image insertion here

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, gboard

I've seen similar questions asked regarding Flutter and other applications, but to give some context, Google's Gboard just changed the way GIFs and emojis insert into the application, but it's unclear how to support it now.

The error above appears when using Gboard to insert an image into an HTML input. I assume there's some way to accept this, but there does not appear to be any documentation on this apart from the obscure change notes on Gboard that say they changed the way they do it.

Answer (score 2):

This was probably fixed in the newest update by Gboard. You can install an APK of an older version of Gboard [here](https://google-keyboard.en.uptodown.com/android/versions) and the easiest way to downgrade Gboard for iOS is using a tweak called AppStore ++ but that only works if you are jailbroken.

Otherwise, just try other keyboards such as SwiftKey or Giphy to insert the image into your HTML input.

Comment: I've checked for a new release of Gboard and nothing is available yet that changes anything. I'm aware that I can downgrade, but I'm developing software, so the point is to make sure my users can still attach GIFs, not just so I can.

Comment: Tell your users to get the Giphy keyboard then. That should support opening GIFs always because that is what that keyboard was created for.

Comment: That's not a reasonable solution to using my app. I'd be very annoyed if a company told me to stop using my preferred keyboard because I wasn't competent enough to support it.

Comment: There is no other solution then unless Google decides to fix it. Since you have an App, why don't you make your own keyboard that supports adding GIFs? Also, you can use multiple keyboards.

Comment: I don't believe it's something they broke, I think it's a change they made along the lines of clipboard pasting, but different.

Comment: Can you share what device you're using so I can test it for myself?

Comment: Sure, it's a Pixel 2 XL